# Regular expression for vehicle registration number that should exclude special characters

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have used this pattern but it is allowing special characters. how to exclude them.

```
ng-pattern ="/^([A-Z]{2,3}[0-9]{2}[A-Z0-9]{1,4}[0-9]{1,4})|([A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3})|([A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{1,4})|[^@]|$/"
```

Comment: Which special characters? If it's just `^` and `@`, then remove "`|[^@]`." It could also be an implementation error.

Comment: Please change the why you ask your question, it's not clear what you want.

Comment: I need a pattern for vehicle registration number, number can be alphanumeric but should not contain any special characters

Answer (score 0):

This `[^@]` will match any character except `@`. Get rid of that condition and it should be matching alphanumeric strings.

It would help to see an example input + expected output, but I have a working example [here](https://regex101.com/r/AgOXmg/1) if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern mentioned contains 5 possible components which are separated by OR `|`

1. ^([A-Z]{2,3}[0-9]{2}[A-Z0-9]{1,4}[0-9]{1,4}) - Start with pattern then accepts special characters or any other characters
2. ([A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}) - *matches any pattern*THIS PATTERN*mathches any other pattern*
3. ([A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{1,4}) - *matches any pattern*THIS PATTERN*mathches any other pattern*
4. [^@] - Matches any pattern that does not contain @
5. $ - Matches any pattern

If I understood right (I am not sure of the 4th component) I believe you would like components ^(1|2|3)$, where component 1 is not prefixed with ^

`/^(([A-Z]{2,3}[0-9]{2}[A-Z0-9]{1,4}[0-9]{1,4})|([A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3})|([A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{1,4}))$/`